# How do Google Chrome's automatic suggestions work without an internet connection?

Tags: google-chrome, algorithm

Google Chrome's automatic suggestions works even without an internet connection?

Even after that I deleted cache and data.

How is that possible?

Comment: Are the suggestions things you've searched for in the past, or generic suggestions? Please specify how you deleted the cache and data. Are you perhaps trying to clear your browser history more thoroughly?

Comment: Generic suggestions, for sure. Things that I didn't even know. I deleted data and cache from the settings of the Chrome's app

Comment: When I've installed a basic Chrome install, it always has a collection of basic search suggestions immediately on first run. I'm not surprised that Google has simply pre-loaded things like this in some sort of compressed dictionary file. HOW it works is a bit beyond this site, though. While Chromium is open source and so such things may be known at that, Chrome itself is not open source and its internal features may not be known beyond what Google publishes regarding it.

Comment: Take a look at `chrome://predictors/` to see whether the suggestions are based on past activity in any way. It looks like offline chrome suggestions in the dropdown are just using a basic auto-complete text model for your language like a phone keyboard, but yeah Google doesn't publish specifics

Comment: I don't know why. For example, tried a couple of minutes ago and if I type "bridge" It suggests me "bridge Baltimora" or "bridge crash"...like if It Is updated